# Saving a HasMany relationship data with a compound index in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, has-many, cakephp-model

I'm currently using CakePHP 2.x.

I make all my forms using the form_helper and then the active record way to save the model data. It's really tidy and simple, but I can't find the way to save one particular structure.

I've 2 tables, one for the user basic information and one for the user details, with a lot of different fields: User and User_Detail.

```
User:

id | name | email
------------------------
1  | John | john@doe.com
2  | Paul | paul@doe.com

User_Detail:
id | user_id | field  | value
-----------------------------
1  | 1       | sex    | m
2  | 1       | age    | 21
3  | 2       | height | 180
```

What's the best way to make the user fill some fields? What fields to complete can be hardcoded in the app. Is it possible using a form helper and saveRelationship()?

Comment: where "sex", "age", "height" come from? are they constant strings? or are they just open inputs that the user fills in the form?

Comment: They are constant strings, but I will have a lot of them, and not every user will have the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I would add a new table that contains the name of the "custom fields", lets call it "custom_fields" and this would be its definition

custom_fields:
id
name

Its model is called CustomField and it hasMany UserDetail

Your user_details table will have this structure

user_details:
id
user_id
custom_field_id
value

This model (UserDetail) belongsTo CustomField.

Your model User hasMany UserDetail.

Now, in your users form you might want to have a select with all possible CustomValues, in order to do this you previously did something like this in your controller

```
$customValues = $this->CustomValues->find('list');
$this->set(compact('customValues'));
```

So, in your view you will have something like this

```
echo $this->Form->input('UserDetail.custom_field_id', array('type' => 'select', 'values' => $customValues));
echo $this->Form->input('UserDetail.value')
```

And of course, after submitting this form you will call [Model::SaveAssociated](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array)

I hope you have now the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand what your trying to do ..... If using Form Helper you can construct your input fields as follows:

```
echo $this->Form->input('User.name');
echo $this->Form->input('User.email');
echo $this->Form->input('User_Detail.sex');
echo $this->Form->input('User_Detail.age');
echo $this->Form->input('User_Detail.height');
```

Then when you save you should use saveAssociated($this->request-data) and it should work by saving the record into both models and automatically creating the appropriate User_Detail.user_id field.

Comment: Jerry, Maybe I'm misinterpreting you, but User_Detail.sex doesn't exists. It should create a new line (or edit the current one) with User_Detail.field = "sex" and User_detail.value = "m"

Comment: Sorry. I lost my mind half way through the response. Forget what I wrote. I understand now what you are looking for. If I have an idea I'll post.

Comment: Nazareno ... one thought. I have occasionally needed to associate a random grouping of name/value pairs (in your case field/value pairs) with a record. One approach I have taken is to create an associative array that looks like $attributes = array('sex' => 'm', 'age' => '21'). This would be different for each User record. I would then serialize the array as follows: $serialized_attributes = json_encode($attributes) and then save the string in the main model (in your case the User model). It worked for my purposes but if you want to search on the data it might be a problem.